# Create Excel file of complete recyclerview

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to create an excel file of complete recyclerview in android studio using java. Please guide me how to do that or a sample please. The model class includes fullname, designation, phone, email and address.

Comment: Use [Apache POI](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/) to write your recyclerview's contents to the excel sheet.

Comment: Can you please write a sample code in a generateExcel() method to fetch model class data to create a excel of complete recyclerview.

Comment: Here's a working demo in normal java: https://www.dropbox.com/s/in3emy194g8bwpf/Main.java?dl=0. In android you'd have to add the gradle dependencies for `apache poi` and `apache poi-ooxml`. Retrieve the model class data used to create your `RecyclerView` and call the appropriate `Apache poi` methods I've shown to create an excel sheet.

Comment: The code was adapted from [How to write excel files in java with apache poi](https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-write-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi) by Nam Ha Minh.

Comment: Apache poi is not working, creating issues in app. Errors are shown in logcat "Duplicate xmlbeans" .

Comment: Can you post a seperate question with your gradle file and errors?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.